# how to get random 10 digits in robotframework?(any 10 digits)

Tags: robotframework

`${PO_Number}    Generate random string    4    0123456789`

I am using above code but it is not entering random 4 digits to field. It is entering just 4 into the field.
I have tried below lines as well but not worked.

`${numbers}=    Evaluate    random. Sample(range(1, 11), 4)    random`

Is there any simple logic to get 10 random digits.(not unique)?
or please let me know if I am wrong

thanks in advance

Comment: You seems to be confused in your question. _`get 10 random digits.(not unique)?`_ there will be many possible combinations of 10 digits which will be unique and random at same time. `It is entering just 4 into the field.` this line is out of context for the heading of the question. The first line will give you the random number string of length 4.Please read [mcve] and edit your post accordingly.

Comment: _"I am using above code but it is not entering random 4 digits to field."_ - why do you expect that line of code to enter anything? All it does is generate a random string and store it in `${PO_Number}`. It doesn't enter it anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

If you need non unique and non random number simply declare variable of 10 digits and use it.

```
*Test cases
${PO_Number}=      9876530112
```

This line should generate you the 4 random digits from the 0-9 digits

```
${number}=    Generate random string        4     0123456789
```

Output from the above line -

[image]

To get the 10 random and unique digits use-

```
${number}=    Generate random string        10     0123456789
```

**Output - **

[image]

have a look for any other variation of [random strings](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/String.html#Generate%20Random%20String)